# MongoDB: retrieve, filter and sort MongoDB embedded collections

Tags: jquery, asp.net, mongodb, linq

Following simple structure (post.comments)

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("59acf254af58fa08ecbb4389"),
"title" : "no title",
"total_comments" : 4874,
"comments" : [ 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59acf275af58fa08ecbb4399"),
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-04T06:28:05.238Z"),
        "body" : "Dummy Comment Title",
    }, 
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("59acf275af58fa08ecbb439f"),
        "timestamp" : ISODate("2017-09-04T06:28:05.488Z"),
        "body" : "Dummy Comment Title",
    }, 
    { ... thousand comments more ... }
],
```

Fetching posts and ignore comments due to massive data:

```
BGStream stream = await db.Streams
            .Find(m => m.Id == new ObjectId(id))
            .Project<BGStream>(Builders<BGStream>.Projection
               .Exclude(m => m.Comments))
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Fetching missing comments via ajax from comments controller with limit (*not a nice solution*):

```
var filter = Builders<BGStream>.Filter.Eq("_id", new ObjectId(id));
var projection = Builders<BGStream>.Projection
          .Include(m => m.Comments).Slice("comments", skip: skip, limit: take);
var stream = await db.Streams
    .Find(filter).Project<BGStream>(projection)
    .FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

**Problem:** 
I have no idea how to sort the comments collection by timestamp. I have to fetch the most recent comments at first but the query gives me the oldest first.

What I am missing here?

Comment: If you have thousands of comments as you mentioned in your question, I'd suggest to think about splitting your document and moving comments into separate collection. This will give you more freedom of fetching comments and reconstructing document they way you want. see `$lookup` in documentation

Comment: Thought about it already but CRUD actions are hard to implement if I split this. Delete chains and so on...

Comment: Going to implement extra collections. Thx Saleem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use aggregation with [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operation as follows

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
    {
        "$unwind" : "$comments"
    },
    {
        "$sort" : {
            "comments.timestamp" : -1
        }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            "_id" : null,
            "comments" : {
                "$push" : "$comments"
            }
        }
    }
])
```

You can use [$limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) to limit the number of comments

Comment: This is a working solution but after calling $unwind I have to handle anonymous BSONObjects. I think its better to store comments in an extra collection as Saleem mentioned above.